# pivoting varchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

[image]

I want to convert the raw data to pivoted data and below is my code:

```
    select CVID, CID, sum(case when ext_id = 'q_begin' then ans else 0 end) as [q_begin],
                  sum(case when ext_id  = 'q_end' then answer else 0 end) as [q_end]
from #temp group by CVID, CID;
```

I am unable to complete this snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave out the `else` and use `max()`:

```
select CVID, CID,
       max(case when ext_id = 'q_begin' then ans end) as [q_begin],
       max(case when ext_id  = 'q_end' then ans end) as [q_end]
from #temp
group by CVID, CID;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't `SUM` dates, you'll need to use `MIN` or `MAX`. Other than that, you also need to `GROUP BY` the `QUART` column.

So, the code you need to use should be:

```
SELECT  CVID, 
        CID, 
        QUART,
        MIN(CASE WHEN ext_id = 'q_begin' THEN ans END) [q_begin],
        MIN(CASE WHEN ext_id  = 'q_end' THEN ans END) [q_end]
FROM #temp 
GROUP BY CVID, 
         CID,
         QUART
;
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can PIVOT

```
select      *
from        #temp
pivot       (
                max(ans)
                for ext_id in ([q_begin], [q_end])
            ) p
```